# Media Foundation: Cannot change a FPS on webcam

Tags: c++, webcam, directshow, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I try to replace codes  with Directshow ("DS") on Media Foundation ("MF") in my app and met one problem - cannot set a needed fps using MF on a webcam. MF allowed me to set only 30 fps. If I try to set 25 fps, I always get the error 0xc00d5212 on SetCurrentMediaType().  In DS I could change that parameter.

My codes:

```
ASSERT(m_pReader); //IMFSourceReader *m_pReader;
IMFMediaType *pNativeType = NULL;
IMFMediaType *pType = NULL;
UINT32 w = 1280; 
UINT32 h = 720; 
UINT32 fps = 25; // or 30

DWORD dwStreamIndex = MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM;

// Find the native format of the stream.
HRESULT hr = m_pReader->GetNativeMediaType(dwStreamIndex, 0, &pNativeType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}

GUID majorType, subtype;

// Find the major type.
hr = pNativeType->GetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, &majorType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}
// Define the output type.
hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}
hr = pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, majorType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}
// Select a subtype.
if (majorType == MFMediaType_Video)
{
    subtype= MFVideoFormat_RGB24;
}
else
{
  //error
}
hr = pType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, subtype);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, w, h);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, fps, 1);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
  //error
}
hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(dwStreamIndex, NULL, pType);
if (FAILED(hr))
{// hr = 0xc00d5212 
  //!!!!!error - if fps == 25 
}
return hr;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It might so happen that the camera does not support flexible frame rate values, and can work with only among the supported set, for example: 10, 15, 20, 24, 30 fps. You should be able to enumerate supported media types and choose the one that works for you - those media types typically include frame rate options.

Even though Media Foundation and DirectShow video capture eventually ends up in the same backend, there might be discrepancies in behavior. Specifically, you are working with Media Foundation higher level API that internally interfaces to a media source, and it might so happens that frame rate leads to `0xC00D5212` `MF_E_TOPO_CODEC_NOT_FOUND` "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content" confusion even though technically the driver can capture in respective mode.

See also:

- [Get all supported FPS values of a camera in Microsoft Media Foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815015/get-all-supported-fps-values-of-a-camera-in-microsoft-media-foundation)
- [Media Foundation Video/Audio Capture Capabilities](http://alax.info/blog/1579)

Comment: Hi Roman, I tried your MF utility and got  the followings: my webcam can work only with 1 and 30 fps. But DS shown another things -  5, 10, 15, 20, 25 and 30 fps. Why? Or a webcam has only 30 fps, but DS can divides that fps on the other frame rates? is it true?

Comment: I think WDM driver reports multiple frame rates but the information might be incomplete and filtered out by MF layer. Just a guess - there is no sufficient information to tell anything definite.

Comment: Hi, I think that this limitation is related with UVC - USB Video Class - driver for Media Foundation. It is targeted on platform WindowsStore and is optimized for working with USB cameras for getting video not only with RGB and MJPEG formats, but with H264 and H265 formats from hardware encoders - so it leads for limitation of functionality. For getting more functionality you should use DShow or write timer, which will grab frames with the needed frame rate.

Comment: Evgeny, thank you for information. if I remain DS in the app, then MF is not  necessary at all. My goal is to upgrade my DS app to MF. The timer is a poor idea too, additional CPU loading.

Comment: A rule of thumb is: if you can (possible, acceptable) use DirectShow for specific task, you will be good going this way, for many reasons. Maintenance, extensibility specifically. Especially when it goes about video capture. Media Foundation does have its really clever bits, but not a superseding replacement.

Comment: ok, maybe you are right. What do you think about DS support  by Microsoft in future?

Comment: DS is declared old and I think that Microsoft has stopped development of it - of course it will be supported in future OS, but situation will the same like GDI - supporting, but stop improvement. Microsoft invested more money in WindowsStore and in it's environment. If you would like - you can search my code on CodeProject  [capturing-live-video](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/776058/capturing-live-video-from-web-camera-on-windows-an) - it uses media session of MF or [CaptureManager SDK](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK) - it is more powerful.

Comment: DirectShow development is in a dead end. However there are too many products out there relying on DirectShow, including Microsoft's own Skype and Skype for Business, so it is maintained with minimal support possible. It's unlikely to go away, and, well, VFW is also still here. New development goes to MF, but it does not look like developer friendly and it does not offer advantages over DirectShow in part of video capture in particular. I think I will have to deal with both APIs over some long time.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the timer for fps control imitation into the codes. So at the start I set 30 fps , then by fps scale I skip some frames for my app.
Thank you for help.